# Discord JS (Bot Presence)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So, in Discord, users can have a custom status, however, when I try to set my bot up with one nothing happens...Even though `CUSTOM_STATUS` is available

I have `bot.user.setPresence({ activity: { name: "Testing", type: "CUSTOM_STATUS" }, status: "online" });`
inside of the `ready` event. I was just wondering why this doesn't work and if there is a work around

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType).

> Bots cannot set a CUSTOM_STATUS, it is only for custom statuses received from users

The valid types you could choose from are:

- PLAYING
- STREAMING
- LISTENING
- WATCHING

Answer (score 0):

Try client.user.setActivity(`Your Status`)
I am using this and its working fine
If you are using v12 then i cant help you

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that your setPresence command is in your ready event. For example, this is my ready command:

```
const {PREFIX} = require('../config.json');
const { Message } = require('discord.js');
const message = require('./message.js');

//must update when new module.exports event happens
const leaveEvent = require('../util/guildMemberRemove');
const invitecounterEvent = require('../util/guildMemberAddinvitecounter');
const modmailEvent = require('../util/modmail');

module.exports = (client, message) => {

    //must update when new module.exports event happens
    leaveEvent(client);
    invitecounterEvent(client);
    modmailEvent(client);

    console.log(' ');
    console.log(`Hi, ${client.user.username} is now online! My Prefix is ${PREFIX}`);
    console.log(`Bot has started, with ${client.users.size} users, in ${client.channels.size} channels of ${client.guilds.size} guilds.`); 
    //client.user.setActivity(`Serving ${client.guilds.size} servers`); (big servers only)
    client.user.setActivity('U', { type: 'WATCHING' }) //PLAYING, STREAMING, LISTENING, WATCHING, CUSTOM_STATUS
        .then(presence => console.log(`Activity set to: WATCHING ${presence.activities[0].name}`))
        .catch(console.error);


    console.log(`Ready as ${client.user.tag} to serve in ${client.channels.cache.size} channels on ${client.guilds.cache.size} servers, for a total of ${client.users.cache.size} users.`);

    client.generateInvite(['SEND_MESSAGES', 'MANAGE_GUILD', 'MENTION_EVERYONE', 'ADMINISTRATOR',])
    .then(link => {
        console.log(`Generated bot invite link: ${link}`);
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
        inviteLink = link;
    });

};
```

The part that should help you is `client.user.setActivity('U', { type: 'WATCHING' })` 
The different types you can do are PLAYING, STREAMING, LISTENING, and WATCHING.